# Why keras neural networks are so slow?

Tags: python, neural-network, cpu, theano, keras

I installed keras with theano backend and try to train some network from
https://blog.thoughtram.io/machine-learning/2016/11/02/understanding-XOR-with-keras-and-tensorlow.html
I use CPU right now.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
import time

# the four different states of the XOR gate
training_data = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]], "float32") #line 1
#training_data = np.random.random((10000, 2)) #line2

# the four expected results in the same order
target_data = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]], "float32") #line3
#target_data = np.random.random((10000, 1))  #line4

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

start = time.time()
model.fit(training_data, target_data, nb_epoch=500, verbose=0)
print "time: " + str(time.time() - start)

print model.predict(training_data).round()
```

Having `line1` and `line3` uncommented, I get

```
time: 2.50199985504
```

After this result I thought that I should use bigger trainingset because numpy optimized for huge arrays, but

having `line2` and `line4` uncommented, I get

```
time: 186.332000017
```

The same result I get using theano without keras.
Why keras and theano so slow or what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Try playing with the batch size, you might get a speed up for your line 2 and 4.

Otherwise I don't see what's wrong... you train over 500 * 10000 = 5 Million samples, it takes more time than over 500 * 4 = 2 K samples...

Comment: Thank you, But the main question now is not about optimising, the main question about what's wrong. If I build in Matlab the similar network, it will be faster even without batch. I don't understand why.

Comment: There is not enough detail to tell you what is wrong, it could be that theano doesn't have a C compiler available and it is running a python implementation, which is extremely slow.